# Problema al mostrar tilde en correos electrónicos enviados

Tags: email, java-ee, java-8

Hola a todos espero me puedan apoyar un favor tengo una aplicación en `Jsp`  y `Servlet` que me permite enviar un correo electrónico a través de Gmail, pero no reconoce la `tilde` en su lugar aparece `Ã`.
**Este es mi código**

```
public static void EnviarCorreoElectronico(String Destinatario, String Asunto, String MensajeTexto){
    final String Username = "ancasi.daniel.2@gmail.com";
    final String Password = "abcde";

    Properties props = new Properties();  

    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
            return new PasswordAuthentication(Username, Password);
        }
    });

    try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Username));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(Destinatario)); 
        message.setSubject(Asunto);
        message.setText(MensajeTexto);
        Transport.send(message); 
        System.out.println("Correo enviado.");
    }catch(MessagingException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

A continuación dentro de mi código agregé los caracteres **"UTF-8"** y **"text/html; charset=utf-8"** a `setSubject` y a `setText` tal como se muestra en la parte de abajo, pero al enviar el correo sigue mostrando el mismo caracter diferente a la tilde (`Ã`).

```
message.setSubject("Correo de prueba", "UTF-8");
message.setText("Haciendo pruebas con la letra ñ y las tildes como: Camión","UTF-8");
```

**Este es el resultado al enviar un correo a un destinatario.**
[image: Problema no reconoce la tilde en el correo electronico]
**¿Hay alguna solución a esto?, se les agradece mucho de antemano.**

Comment: antes de setSubject por message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"");

Comment: @oegpyg puse tu código antes del `message.setSubject("Correo de prueba");` pero los resultados son los mismos.

Comment: @oegpyg gracias por tu gran apoyo que también me sirvió, ya encontré la solución a este problema lo comentaré como resultado.

Comment: intentaste poner los caracteres especiales como entidades HTM? `&eacute;` por ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno la solución a este problema es debido a que en mi Servlet no recibe los caracteres en UTF-8 desde JSP.
Deben incluir en el Servlet lo siguiente.

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Mientras que en el `response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8")` envía caracteres especiales, `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` este código recibe caracteres especiales de JSP.
**"Lo comparto por si ha alguien más le sirve."**

Answer (score 3):

a mi me funciono utilizando el `charset=ISO-8859-1`, ejemplo:

```
mail.setContent(testMail.getTexto(), "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```